# can someone just quickly explain the notation here, thank you

Tags: notation, vectors, physics, mathematical-physics, polar-coordinates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXWb2.png)

$$\boxed{\vec r=r\,\hat r}$$

thats all thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Absent context, there is no way to guess.  Generally speaking, notation that appears in a reference ought to be defined there.

Comment: a vector ($\overrightarrow r$) can be thought of as the product of its length ($r$) and a unit vector in the same direct ($\hat r$).

Comment: The $r := \left\Vert \overrightarrow{r} \right\Vert_2 $ is the length of the vector, $\hat{r}$ is the normalized version of $\overrightarrow{r}$ - so a vector of length 1 pointing in the same direction. So this says that a vector is its direction vector scaled up to its length. Note that this is all just convention an in other contexts could be very different

Comment: While this is a very common notational convention in physics, which is why three people were able to immediately give an answer despite the criticism, for any similar questions in the future, you should at the very least tell where you encountered the notation. And almost certainly, lulu is correct that simply searching in your source would have found the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector $\vec{r}$ is in length r in the direction of the unit vector $\hat{r}$ .

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.